# What is the difference between M4A and AAC Audio Files?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac, m4a

Is there any difference between M4A audio files and AAC audio files or are they exactly
the same thing but with a different file extension?

Answer (score 40):

`.M4A` files typically contain audio only and are formatted as MPEG-4 Part 14 files (`.MP4` container).

`.AAC` is not a container format and instead it is a raw MPEG-4 Part 3 bitstream with audio stream encoded.

Note that M4A does not have to contain exactly AAC audio, there are other valid options as well.

Comment: Isn't it the case that `.M4A` is a container separate from the .`MP4` container, the former being an audio container - in the same way that `.M4V` is a video container - whereas the latter, by contrast, is a container for *both audio and video*? Your answer seems to simply imply `.M4A` files use `.MP4` containers, which is not how I understand things.

Comment: @Hashim: M4A and MP4 (and other) are extensions that suppose container format known as MP4. The structure of data is exactly the same, it's just choice of extension of M4A that suggests that the file might have audio only (which is not a strict condition, rather more of a hint).

Comment: So M4A is not a codec? I'm trying to understand why the FFmpeg interface in Accord.NET gives AAC and M4A as choices for audio codecs.

Comment: @KyleDelaney M4A is not a codec. MP4/M4A/M4V are all interchangeable file extensions that are used for convenience to refer to the same MP4 container format, as a hint to the enclosed media type. M4A: audio only, M4V: video only, MP4 (and sometimes M4V): both. The most common codecs used for MP4 files are H.264 video and AAC audio. If M4A is listed as a codec option, it likely just gives you a choice between multiple standard MP4 audio codecs (or if not, is just AAC with different options).

Comment: Adding to comments from @Beejor to try and help clarify for folks: M4A, MP4, and MV4 are containers. In reference to the OP, .AAC is a file extension, and AAC is a codec. Making matters more confusing (of course!), AAC is one of the few audio codecs that is capable of standing alone, and it may also be included ("contained") inside a container (such as MP4). Re-capping: AAC is a codec and can also be a File Extension. M4A is a container. M4A is not a codec.

Answer (score 15):

There are raw video and audio streams, this streams cannot be played directly on most video/audio player, they need to be "encapsulated" on a transport, a raw H.264 video stream and a raw AAC audio stream need to be inside a MP4 encapsulator, it can be also inside an AVI or MOV encapsulator.

A MP4 file can contain a H.264 video stream and/or an AAC audio stream, but for some reason someone decided that a MP4 file that contains video and audio use the file extension M4V (v for video) and if it is an MP4 file that only contains audio to use the M4A extension, that is a common practice in other encapsulators like Windows Media which use WMV and WMA, or OGG which use OGV and OGA, silly as it seems.

So a file that has a M4A file extension is an MP4 file that can contain a AAC audio track but it is not always the case, that's why programs like mediainfo become handy to know what is inside a file.

Comment: Where can I read more about your statement that some audio players [as of 2013] can play only "encapsulated" files but not raw streams?

Comment: Just try to playback an AAC track on iTunes or Windows Media without using a MP4 encapsulation.

Comment: I don't have iTunes. Windows Media Player version 12.0.18362 can play it. To me it sounds like "ecapsulated" is raw AAC plus extra headers, i.e. more difficult to parse than raw. So I'm wondering whether I'm wrong that raw AAC is *simpler*, or otherwise why raw AAC is supported less often.

Comment: Here is a great article which explains the difference between codecs and containers: https://tubularinsights.com/file-formats-containers-compression/

Comment: The link doesn't answer my question: why raw AAC is supported less often. But I have a theory now. Since video with audio is always in a container, programmers *have to* implement reading of video+audio containers; then from there it might be easier to implement reading of audio containers than reading of raw audio.

Answer (score 9):

They are not the same thing.

An `.m4a` file is basically the same thing as an `mp4`; it is only a container format. `codec != container` It does not imply a codec, and therefore it can only contain `mp3`, `ac3` or any other audio codec.

An `.aac` file contains concatenated AAC frames pre-pended with ADTS headers (and optionally an ID3 tag).

Comment: can you please help me if you know which type of codec is used for `aac` and `m4a`??

Comment: `aac` is a codec, so the codec is `aac`, `m4a` is a container, so it can be any codec.