# Reading/writing various audio file metadata in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, audio, windows-10, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to modify the metadata of some audio files in C++, and I came across [what I thought was] a possible way using Windows Media Foundation. So I tried to put together a simple solution:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mfplat.lib")


int main() {
    HRESULT hr;

    CComPtr<IMFSourceResolver> source_resolver(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr = MFCreateSourceResolver(&source_resolver))) {
        // Handle errors...
    }

    MF_OBJECT_TYPE object_type = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;
    CComPtr<IUnknown> source_object(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr = source_resolver->CreateObjectFromURL(L"audio_file_here", MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE | MF_RESOLUTION_READ | MF_RESOLUTION_CONTENT_DOES_NOT_HAVE_TO_MATCH_EXTENSION_OR_MIME_TYPE, NULL, &object_type, &source_object))) {
        // Handle errors...
    }

    CComPtr<IMFMediaSource> source(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr = source_object->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&source)))) {
        // Handle errors...
    }

    CComPtr<IMFPresentationDescriptor> presentation_descriptor(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr = source->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&presentation_descriptor))) {
        // Handle errors...
    }

    CComPtr<IMFMetadataProvider> metadata_prov(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr = MFGetService(source, MF_METADATA_PROVIDER_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&metadata_prov)))) {
        // Handle errors...
    }

    CComPtr<IMFMetadata> metadata(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr = metadata_prov->GetMFMetadata(presentation_descriptor, 0, NULL, &metadata))) {
        // Handle errors...
    }

    /* Use metadata, etc etc */
}
```

It works fine for a standard MP3 (.mp3) file, yet it always fails on AAC (.m4a from iTunes) audio files. Specifically, the `MFGetService()` function fails with a return value given by Visual Studio as `"The object does not support the specified service."`.

I don't understand why this is the case. Right [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757927(v=vs.85).aspx) it says Media Foundation supports AAC, and Windows definitely supports it *somehow*, because I can play my AAC files perfectly fine via the in-built Groove Music player.
Furthermore, the file metadata is also readable by Windows *somehow*, because I can view the properties of the file in Explorer, which it lists the title, artist, album, etc just fine.

**So how can I read and write metadata from MP3 *and* AAC audio files? Is it possible through Media Foundation, or do I need another tool from the Windows APIs?** (I've seen reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to a method involving a "Windows Shell interface", is that the way to go?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your question is not actually related to AAC. You don't do AAC files here and your file is a MPEG-4 file (typically .MP4 however your .M4A is just a variant/alias of .MP4).

- [What is the difference between M4A and AAC Audio Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18111039/868014)

So the question is whether you can access the metadata of MPEG-4 file using `MF_METADATA_PROVIDER_SERVICE` or otherwise with Media Foundation.

Note that "support for AAC or MPEG-4" does not necessarily means metadata management as metadata management is, after all, an auxiliary capability.

It seems Microsoft deprecated metadata provider service and is no longer offering it for new media sources. Even though support for `MF_METADATA_PROVIDER_SERVICE` remains available for .MP3 files, it is no longer offered for .MP4. Instead, Microsoft suggests use of shell property handlers, which, for MP4 files, recourse to Media Foundation internally.

See [MF_METADATA_PROVIDER_SERVICE for MP4 file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/582624bc-b3ce-48d6-999b-0de2db243c7a/mfmetadataproviderservice-for-mp4-file?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment):

> To get metadata from the MP4 source you should actually get the IPropertyStore interface from the `MF_PROPERTY_HANDLER_SERVICE` service. MSDN is being updated to document **this new method** of retrieving metadata...
>
> For info, the standard Shell property keys are documented here: [Windows Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd561977).

Shell and explorer use exactly this method to retrieve the metadata.

You can also use [FilePropertyStore](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Toolbox/FilePropertyStore-x64.exe) tool from [there](http://alax.info/blog/1505) to quickly list properties available via shell property handler API:

[image]

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure the file I was using *was* AAC, unless iTunes is completely wrong (Isn't .m4a the container it uses for AAC audio anyway?). In any case still a useful answer; doesn't seem to be clear at all from the documentation that it was deprecated.

Comment: AAC is encoding of audio track inside MP4 file. The metadata is located in the structure of MP4 file rather than related to audio encoding. Hence, you're interested in metadata for MP4 file rather than metadata for AAC file. Media Foundation does have *some* support for raw AAC files, however there is no metadata at all there.